# How does SO enforce the daily vote limits?

Tags: discussion, voting

Does the system have to do a COUNT(*) query on the user's votes for the day, then determine if the daily limit is reached? Or is there another method to doing this?

Comment: Is this really relevant?

Comment: @alex: not to the operation of SO, but perhaps to the learning of anyone interested.

Comment: @John Then it really should belong to SO.

Comment: @badp: "Belong to SO"? Do you mean "belong *on* SO"?  According to the FAQs, questions about the core Stack Exchange engine that powers all Stack Exchange websites are welcome here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We do exactly what you describe.. we `count(*) for utc today` on the existing votes every time you vote, and when you hit the limit, we tell you to come back in (n) hours to vote more!

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking if there's another way to do so, then obviously yes.

In the user table, add a column for each vote limit. Reset the columns every night to the appropriate vote allowance. Decrement the value every time you use a vote. Check the value to know how many votes are left.

Similarly, for rate limited actions, add a column with the timestamp of the last time you changed something. Do a date diff to know how much time has passed and deny or allow accordingly.

Is this what SE does? I don't know. It might be. It might not. I have never really done databases, so I don't know how horrible this idea is.